# No icons, and marks are getting displayed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

the icons in the Central Administrationof MOSS 2007 are not getting displayed . It is showing a cross sign and teh message attached to the cross is **USE Shift + Enter to open the menu [new window]**

Comment: couple questions, is this a new install? What browser are you using to connect to Central Admin? What icons in particular are not showing? Just icons or all images?

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler to see the message returned when it requests the images.